# Network extension via wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

We have both wired and wifi networks in our house.  We want to provide wifi to a workshop in a back garage.  The wifi signal is pretty good *outside* at that point, but *inside* the garage it doesn't work very well.  That wall is pretty metal-laden, so I don't think just a repeater through it would work, at least not very well.

I have a general idea that I might be able to hang an *outdoor* wifi device that could tie into the home wifi network, and then connect through a wired network into the garage/workshop, where I would have another wifi device that would broadcast a different wifi signal.  But I don't know what the devices that I would need are called (bridge, client, access point, router?), or if this even possible (can you have a second wifi network within a larger network that was already wirelessly "bridged" (not sure if I'm using "bridged" in the formal way it is defined in networking terminology))?

I've done quite a bit of research, but see contradictory information.  Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options.

- One device that by itself provides solid access in your house and in your back workshop.

  - Not likely within FCC limits.  Maybe if you replace your metal-laden walls, but I doubt it.
- Two devices that are NOT on the same unified setup that by themselves provide sufficient solid access in both places

  - This is NOT the best solution... but it is the cheapest
  - You're going to drop connections going back and forth, lose your phone calls, etc. as your devices have to roam from one to the other.
  - I'd recommend looking at the [Ubiquiti Unifi](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#unifi) line first, for the price sensitive.

    - The UAP-AC-Pro and above are rated for indirect outdoor mounting; however, there are signficant electrical concerns for outdoor mounting.  Study up if you try that, and look to fibre optic isolation (GBIC's and transcievers are cheap)
    - The CloudKey makes it easy to set up; a Raspberry Pi on a small UPS also works as a controller.
- A mesh setup, two devices that ARE on the same unified setup

  - Remember, mesh by nature drops speed in half for each node away from your hardwired connection, but having a mesh point inside the garage might - MIGHT - work.  Probably have performance issues.
  - Maybe look at the [Ubiquiti Unifi](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#unifi) or the [AmpliFi](https://www.amplifi.com/) lines first, for the price sensitive, or one of [the consumer mesh systems](https://www.pcmag.com/roundup/350795/the-best-wi-fi-mesh-network-systems) if you really want to take a risk, or investigate commercial mesh networks.
  - This is a high risk solution.  Mesh has a lot of issues still.
  - If it does work right, devices should roam automatically and quickly
- A full scale, high performance solution, with two dedicated wireless sections; one section to provide 802.11ac wifi at your various sites, and a second, different section to provide your transparent bridging backbone.

  - 802.11ac provided by, you guessed it, [Ubiquiti Unifi](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#unifi).

    - No need for the more expensive units - start with a pair of UAP-AC-Lite and a CloudKey controller
    - They're both going to be wired, one in the house (prepare to put a second in the house to cover areas of poor coverage)
    - Set them both up on the same wireless network, but DIFFERENT frequencies 1/6/11 for 2.4Ghz, and spread them out widely for 5Ghz.
  - Transparent bridge backbone provided by [Ubiquiti AirMax](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#airmax)

    - These units get yet again another well spread out 5Ghz frequency, and would be - in a very safe, indoors setup at the tiny, tiny ranges you're talking about - be pointed directly at each other, one inside the house wired to your switch/router, and the other inside the garage.

      - Seriously, alignment is critical - take your time pointing them.
    - Nanobeam AC or Nanostation AC would be all you need; a pair total.
  - This is a high performance solution.
  - Devices should roam automatically and quickly, since it's just like having your access points all on the same wired network.

Network

> ```
>        / House UAP(s)
>       / Router 
>       -------CloudKey controller
>       \
>        \ House Nanostation  ~~~radio~~~ Garage Nanostation --- Garage UAP
> ```